# How to test a html5 drag and drop in qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, qunit

I want to test a html 5 drag and drop what i though would work:

From test file

```
var event = new Event('drop',{
    'originalEvent':{
        'dataTransfer':{
            'getData': function(){
                return 'tr#0.sprint'
             }
         }
     },
     stopPropagation': function() {return;}
}
$('tr#0.sprint').trigger(event);
```

This so that the event is triggered and all the functions are set to return what i want tested.

actual script:

Backbone framework

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    ...

    drop : function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('element');

        // some code

    },

    ...

};
```

Sadly this error's to `Illigal function call`

If i remove the `dataTransfer` object and try to set it myself i get a undefined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set it a little different it makes a world of difference:

```
var event = new Event('drop',{
     stopPropagation: function() {return;}
});
event['originalEvent'] ={
    'dataTransfer':{
        'getData': function(){
            return 'tr#0.sprint'
        }
    }
};
$('tr#0.sprint').trigger(event);
```

This is a more 'manual' way of setting attributes of an javascript object. The arguments added to the constructor of the event are checked by the event object's construct.